# Qual a diferença entre usar e não usar chaves na interpolação em strings no PHP?

Tags: php

Qual a diferença entre?

```
$fruta = 'tomate';
echo "{$fruta} é fruta<br>";
echo "$fruta é fruta<br>";
```

Por que alguns programadores usam as chaves (`{}`) se o resultado sem elas é o mesmo?

Comment: Na verdade isto é uma interpolação e não concatenação, que é feito com o `.` em php

Answer (score 4):

De acordo com a [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php), esse recurso de chama interpretação de variáveis dentro de strings. Mas também pode ser chamado de interpolação. Esse não é um exemplo de concatenação. Apesar de serem usados para fazer coisas iguais, são diferentes.

Ainda de acordo com a documentação, existem dois meios de interpretar variáveis em strings, a [sintaxe simples](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple) e a [sintaxe complexa](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex).

Na sintaxe simples, o interpretador procurará por cifrões (`$`) na string e irá substituir pelo valor do identificador. Um exemplo:

```php
$a = 10;
$str = "O número é $a. \n";

echo $str;
```

<sup>[Veja funcionando no Repl.it](https://repl.it/@lffg/SOpt-446896-01)</sup>

No exemplo acima, as chaves são opcionais, já que nenhuma expressão complexa está sendo usada. Portanto, `$a` e `{$a}` produzem o mesmo resultado.

---

A sintaxe complexa, por sua vez, deve ser utilizada para expressões mais complexas, como acessar valores de *arrays* ou propriedades de objetos, que exigem as chaves. Por exemplo:

```php
class Person {
  function __construct($name) {
    $this->name = $name;
  }
}

$person = new Person('Luiz');

$array = ['foo' => 'bar'];

echo "Olá, {$person->name}! \n";
echo "Foo {$array['foo']}! \n";
```

<sup>[Veja funcionando no Repl.it](https://repl.it/@lffg/SOpt-446896-02)</sup>

No exemplo acima, as chaves são mandatórias. Caso contrário, você receberá um erro de *parse*.

---

Note que esse tipo de sintaxe não funciona em *strings* com aspas simples.

> Por que alguns programadores usam as chaves (`{}`) se o resultado sem elas é o mesmo?

Como vimos acima, as chaves são necessárias para expressões complexas. Para expressões simples, no entanto, é provável que sejam utilizadas para manter um padrão.